# How to retry iterator next() after exception

Tags: python, iterator

I have an iterator that sometimes gives me a socket timeout, and I'd like to know how to retry on socket timeout instead of skipping ahead to the next item in the iterator.

The iterator is created using: 
`iterator = pool.imap(process_hit, new_nongeneric_search.scan())`
So I'm calling a function (`process_hit`) on each item in the results of an Elasticsearch query (`new_nongeneric_search.scan()`). Currently when I encounter a timeout, I just catch the exception and move on to calling `next(it)` again.

This is my current approach:

```
while True:
    try:
        next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        logging.info("No more results to process.")
        return
    except socket.timeout:
        logging.warning("Encountered timeout.")
```

If I retry the same item enough times by rerunning the script manually, the timeout will resolve itself, so I'd like to be able to retry the problematic item programmatically instead of just repeating the search multiple times.

Comment: What is the problem with this code? It seems reasonable.

Comment: The code works and is reasonable for some use cases (including mine; it's currently /usable/) but it currently skips the item that's timing out and I'd like to retry it instead of skipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iterator returns nothing, and the iterator interface doesn't support "going back", so you have no ways to "retry" in the code that you gave.

Either return something from your iterator that you can use to "retry", or handle retries inside the iterator's logic (in your case, that would be inside `process_hit()` or `new_nongeneric_search.scan()` depending on what step you are getting timeouts on).